# BigDecimal.valueOf caching mechanism

Tags: java, caching, bigdecimal

I heard that the `BigDecimal.valueOf()` method is better than calling `new BigDecimal()` because it caches common values. I wanted to know how the caching mechanism of `valueOf` works.

Comment: does [this](http://azagorneanu.blogspot.in/2011/07/javamathbigdecimal-performance.html) help you

Comment: I found correct answer in another topic [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561795/6301562)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the JDK 1.8 sources, it looks like it's just a static array which is initialized as part of class initialization - it only caches the values 0 to 10 inclusive, but that's an implementation detail. For example, given dasblinkenlight's post, it looks like earlier versions only cached 0 and 1.

For more detail - and to make sure you're getting information about the JDK which you're actually running - look at the source of the JDK you're using for yourself - most IDEs will open the relevant source code automatically, if they detect the source archive has been included in your JDK installation. Of course, if you're using a different JRE at execution time, you'd need to validate that too.

It's easy to tell whether or not a value has been cached, based on reference equality. Here's a short but complete program which finds the first non-negative value which *isn't* cached:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (long x = 0; x < Long.MAX_VALUE; x++) {
            if (BigDecimal.valueOf(x) != BigDecimal.valueOf(x)) {
                System.out.println("Value for " + x + " wasn't cached");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine with Java 8, the output is:

> Value for 11 wasn't cached

Of course, an implementation *could* always cache the most recently requested value, in which case the above code would run for a very long time and then finish with no output...

Answer (score 1):

If I m not wrong it caches only zero,one, two and ten, Thats why we have only

```
 public static final BigInteger ZERO = new BigInteger(new int[0], 0);
 public static final BigInteger ONE = valueOf(1);
 private static final BigInteger TWO = valueOf(2);
 public static final BigInteger TEN = valueOf(10);
```

That also calls valueOf(x) method.

Comment: Question about BigDecimal and BigDecimal cache from 0 to 10 also ZERO, ONE, TWO and TEN just constant in this class. I don't know why you answered about BigInteger.