# JAVA == with Integers and Doubles

Tags: java

I understand the difference between == and .equals. 
Why the different outcome when using the == operator when it comes to Double and Integer ? Why does JAVA have to treat them differently ?
Double : false

```
Double value1 = 2.2 ; 
Double value2 = 2.2 ;
System.out.println(value1 == value2 );  // false
```

Integer: true

```
Integer num1 = 6 ; 
Integer num2 = 6 ; 
System.out.println(num1 == num2); // true
```

Comment: Note that `==` is reference comparison. I guess the `Integer`s are interned (cached), while the `Double`s are not.

Comment: you should use `value1.equals(value2)` for check it.

Comment: You are comparing references and not values. Either do:

value1.equals(value2);

or do:

value1.doubleValue() == value2.doubleValue();

Comment: Also see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561710/why-does-the-double-valueof-javadoc-say-it-caches-values-when-it-doesnt)

Comment: @kennytm The JLS specifies what `Integer` must cache. No need to guess. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7